# Schengen visa stamped on my expired passport with valid UAE residence visa

Tags: schengen, italy, dubai, filipino-citizens, uae

I am from Philippines working in Dubai, I recently applied for Schengen visa going to Italy, I submitted 2 passports as one of the required documents (renewed and expired since my valid UAE residence visa is on expired passport). When I received the visa I found out they stamped the Schengen visa on my expired passport.

Will that be a problem or I need to send back my passport? I'm worried as I will be travelling on 4th of Sept 2016.

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately. Do not delay even another minute.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem; just carry both passports

Answer (score 3):

Check whether the details in the visa - including the passport number - match the passport information on the passport it is stamped into.

If it matches, you shall be able to use it by carrying two passports. For extra peace of mind you might reach out to the Consulate, explain the situation, and ask if you can travel with it - then print their response, and carry it with you in case there are any issues.

However if it doesn't match (for example they issued a visa for a new passport, but put it into an old passport), then the Consulate made a mistake, and you must contact it ASAP using the contacts they provide at "if the visa details is wrong" section.